# Embed Sharepoint Online sites in external site

Tags: sharepoint-online, embedded

Is there any way to embed Sharepoint sites to an external site at all. I know it's not possible using an iframe because of the x-frame-options deny, but there must be a way to embed just a site or some section to an external site.

I've seen a few services that claim to be able to embed the Sharepoint sites but how do they do it?
Is there a programmatic way? Are there any APIs from Microsoft? I cannot find any documentation at all.
What I want to do is take a Sharepoint site without the Sharepoint header, sidebar and footer, and only embed the main content of the Sharepoint site in a different site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you cannot do that, you can't just extract SPO page in an iframe of another website, the reason is the policy of Microsoft (and i believe everyone adopt this policy). The policy consist of avoiding this kind of external share for security reasons (maybe you will get a webattack, XSS for example). but if you insist to do that search for how to implement a provider hosted app in azure.

Comment: That was my thought too. But I ran into this product here [https://www.valota.live/sharepoint](https://www.valota.live/sharepoint). It claims that it can do exactly what I am looking for. I was wondering how they're doing it because I could not find any documentation for that.

Comment: Based on the description, probably a SharePoint Add-in to pull the information, not display the actual page.

Comment: So, iframing is not possible, which makes sense. But is there a way to get the contents of the site through REST api? There are a tonne of documentation on getting List and Calendar data but I could not find anything for News and Announcement section of the site. I have started looking at [Social Feed](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/get-started-developing-with-social-features-in-sharepoint). Hopefully this can retrieve other site data.

Comment: @Suba S  were you able to solve this? I have the  exact same requirement.